# Consul Watch triggered on each server, cause multiple HTTP calls

Tags: config, alert, watch, consul

I have a Consul cluster of 3 servers. I setup a watch config file for keyprefix (ref below). I deployed the watch to each of my server files.
I deploy the watch to the config folder of each of the servers so that if the leader goes down, then the next leader will have the watch.

The problem I am facing is when a key change triggers the watch, each of the 3 servers then run the handler. Thus making 3 POST calls to the handler service.
How can I make it so only one handler event is called? 
Preferably from the cluster leader.
Or is there a way to only enable watches on specific server instance?

An alternative I thought of is to create a script handler, and with in the script check if it is running on the leader. If so, then create an HTTP call manually.

```
{
    "watches": [{
            "type": "keyprefix",
            "prefix": "port-list/",
            "handler_type": "http",
            "http_handler_config": {
                "path": "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/alert",
                "method": "POST",
                "header": {
                    "x-foo": ["bar", "baz"]
                },
                "timeout": "10s",
                "tls_skip_verify": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution we came up with was to have a dedicated server that has the watches. Obviously, this is not ideal because if that server goes down then then watches go with it.